# Очепятка на странице пустого описания метки

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, описание-метки

На странице полного описания метки полного описания может не быть. Тогда отображается такой текст с очепяткой. Опечатка в количестве нулей: для свободного редактирования нужно `2000` (две тысячи) баллов репутации, а не `20000` (двадцать тысяч).

[image: очепятка]

Comment: Интересно, почему возникла мысль, что должно быть две тысячи.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ за 2000 можно без проверки редактировать вопросы

Comment: @Danis но ведь метка это не вопрос. меток существенно меньше.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ автор этого не знал

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это не дефект. Чтобы редактировать вопросы/ответы без проверки надо иметь `2000` репутации, но даже так при редактировании описания метки она будет попадать в очередь проверки. Проверку можно пропустить только с `20000` репутации:

[справка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user):

> - Редактировать описания меток без последующего одобрения.

так что [статус-так-задумано](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be).